# c3 detect hover over bar

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

I wish to have tooltips AND do some custom stuff when a user hovers over a `.c3-bar`. This is both not supported by the c3 api and made difficult because the way c3 manages pointer events (by using css to turn them off). If I turn `.c3-bar` to `pointer-events:auto !important` tooltips stop working, but otherwise I can't listen to events on `.c3-bar`. Does anyone know how to address this?

I got it to work, but its ugly ugly

```
const c3Hover = 'c3-hover'
const barSelector = '.c3-bar'
const $wrapper = $('#' + this.chart.id)
const getBarRects = () =>
  _.map($wrapper.find(barSelector),
  (bar) => bar.getBoundingClientRect())

$wrapper.on('mousemove', ({clientX,clientY}) =>
  _.reduce(getBarRects(), (acc, {left,right,top,bottom}) =>
    acc  || left <= clientX && clientX <= right
         && top  <= clientY && clientY <= bottom
  , false) ? $wrapper.addClass(c3Hover)
           : $wrapper.removeClass(c3Hover))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in way that reports an event when it hovers over data points, but it seems to fire once per series over a particular x value - i.e. on a bar chart with 2 series it will fire twice. Don't know if that's good enough for your situation?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        onmouseover: function (d) {
            console.log ("yo", d);
        },
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
    }
});
```

outputs:

```
yo Object {x: 0, value: 30, id: "data1", index: 0, name: "data1"}
yo Object {x: 0, value: 130, id: "data2", index: 0, name: "data2"}
```

when moved over the first pair of bars (regardless of the particular one it's actually over)

http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onmouseover

Edit: Aah, I see it also fires when you're not over the actual bar but also in the general vicinity. I guess this doesn't meet your requirements then.

Comment: It does no such thing. Doing so treats the entire `event-rect` as `data`.